# Codeigniter Pagination Not working Properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been trying to learn using the CI framework, and I'm a beginner at PHP too. Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong here. The contents on the page seems to be different but it doesn't show the page no. properly. When I'm at some other page, the page number is still showing the same as the initial one. It doesn't change. Here is my code for pagination. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = site_url("infos/display/$query_id/$sort_by/$sort_order");
    $config['total_rows'] = $data['num_results'];
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['num_links'] = 9;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the `$config['base_url'] = base_url()."infos/display/$query_id/$sort_by/$sort_order";`

- use base_url for your url config, CI's pagination needs the url without the index.php in it, which `site_url` automatically adds.
- and what is on `$data['num_results']` you might want to check if it gives of the proper number of total rows

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. yeah the $data['num_results'] is giving the proper number of total rows. as for the config base url, do you mean i use my base_url same as the one i have set in the config file?

Comment: @loorey no instead of using `site_url` use `base_url`

Comment: i tried that, but now for every page it shows page number 1. The contents are changing though. I just want it to show the correct page number.

Comment: try changing your uri_segment to the number of your url + 1, in your case 6

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I solved this issue. i just had to add $this->pagination->cur_page = $offset; to my controller, with the one tomexsans suggested. It is working like i want :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $config['base_url'] = base_url("index.php/infos/display/$page/$query_id/$sort_by/$sort_order");
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

You mus pass the $page to the controller or vieuw in which you have the pagination.
I mostly do this in controller

```
function openpage() {
$data['page'] = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);
...
...
}
```

make sure you always set the $page.